# Input Security Question in Self Registration for Recovery Password WSO2 IS - Solved

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How to customize security question for recovery password in self register. The default is in the user-portal, can it be moved to self registration? because the user will be most likely forget to input the security question. severity if the user forgets the password and there is no data security question

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to force challenge questions to users in the login flow.

- Login to Management console.
- Navigate to Main Menu, click Resident
  under Identity Providers -> Account Management Policies ->Account
  Recovery.
- **Enable forced challenge questions** and configure **Minimum Number of Forced Challenge Questions to be Answered**.

Please follow the instructions in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/managing-challenge-questions/#making-challenge-questions-mandatory. This will avoid missing security question answering.

Comment: Hi Anuradha, I'm so sorry for the title of the question, should be is "Input Security Question in Self Registration for Recovery Password WSO2 IS". The conclusion is that when a user self-registers, the user is required to input security questions. any advice for this isue?

Comment: Hi Anuradha. Sorry i don't know after i checked, i found its configuration for "Making challenge questions mandatory" and it's work. but I found an error when inputting the question after adding the Challenge Question and then i save but there is an error "Something went wrong. Error occurred while updating the security question"

Comment: @IhsanJazuli Can you please mention your IS version, OS, and provide steps to reproduce the error and stack trace printed on the carbon console?

Comment: I use wso2is version 5.10 and OS (Windows 10).
I have followed the steps in the document above. questions 1 and 2 were saved successfully, but for the addition of question 3 that was created it was not saved successfully. to make sure I make a new claim mapping (for example shoe size) I enter shoe size and then click save. the same can not be saved.

Comment: I replaced the nulls in Mapped Attributes with existing ones which are supported and the problem was solved! but it looks so funny

Comment: If you are using the default LDAP userstore the "Mapped Attribute-Mapped Attribute" under "Claim mapping for the challenge question set" in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/managing-challenge-questions/#adding-a-challenge-question-set should be an existing attribute of the schema.

Comment: Thank you Anuradha for your help